# can i add diffrent colors to events of multiple calendars in a main calendar in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, colors, calendar

I created a site and inside I created some lists of calenders. 
I attached them to my main calendar so I can see all of the events from all my sub calendars. I see them in a month view!.

but now, I can't see which event belong to which sub calendar (or list).
(they have the same color).
I want to see in my main calendar in a month view, which event is belong to each sub calendar?
(so I thought I will use colors, maybe there is a diffrent solution)

can I give each calendar its own color , so each event will get this color and in my main calendar i will see,  let say , event with color yellow then I will know its belong to list (or calendar) X. color blue is belongs to list (or calendar) Y.

if there is another solution it will be also grate . maybe , how can I attach the name of the list to the event so it will apprear together in the main calendar ?

thank you all, 
gadym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could [Christophe's calculated](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/06/tutorial-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-2007-calendar-in-15-minutes/) column/javasript method work for you with a bit of adapting?

[image: Colour coded calendar]

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/06/tutorial-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-2007-calendar-in-15-minutes/